# tkinter columnconfigure is setting my label text to center

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm trying to figure out how to left justify my label text, when I set the columnconfigure so that my controls grow with the window resize the text/control is in the middle but I'd like the text to start at the left. I'm new to tkinter so I might be missing something obvious. I will have several more controls so I'm using the grid layout. Thanks for any guidance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.grid()

        self.label_ccdata_path = Label(master, text='My message goes here')
        self.label_ccdata_path.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `anchor` of your label to the west with `anchor = "w"`

I have modified your code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.grid()

        self.label_ccdata_path = Label(master, text='My message goes here', anchor = "w")
        self.label_ccdata_path.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```